# `span` tag ruins vertical alignment of text?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

When i use `span` tags in my code (to change background of the text based on *what* the text is) the text is not **vertically aligned** vs. its background when i open my code in Android Chrome browser. Let it be [Code v.1](https://jsfiddle.net/p3xzdc9m/) (JSFiddle) and here's the result:

[image: result with <span>]

However, when i *remove* `span` tags the vertical alignment looks perfectly fine. Let it be [Code v.2](https://jsfiddle.net/ahz0ky4u/) (JSFiddle) and here is the result:

[image: result without <span>]

Don't be misleaded by JSFiddle preview window: firstly, be sure to *enlarge* it (alignment disproportion is not seen on *small* window sizes), secondly - Code v.1 in JSFiddle moves the text to the **bottom** of its background, while on Android Chrome the same code moves it to the **top** (see the screenshot above).
What i am **not** looking for:

- JavaScript solutions - *not suitable in my case*
- manual finetuning of the `padding` tag - *the problem is clearly in* `span` *tag, not in padding*

**Here is Code v.1:**

```css
.part_of_speech {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em;
  font-size: calc(0.4em + 1.5vw);
}

.noun {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.adjective {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}

.verb {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.adverb {
  background-color: #f94432;
}

.conjunction {
  background-color: #a047f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="part_of_speech">
  <span class="part_of_speech noun">NOUN</span>
  <span class="part_of_speech adjective">ADJ.</span>
  <span class="part_of_speech verb">VERB</span>
  <span class="part_of_speech adverb">ADV.</span>
  <span class="part_of_speech conjunction">CONJ.</span>
</div>
```

**Here is Code v.2:**

```css
.part_of_speech {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em;
  font-size: calc(0.4em + 1.5vw);
  display: inline-block;
  /* NEW */
  background-color: #2196f3;
  /* MIGRATED FROM .partofspeech CLASSES BELOW */
}


/* .partofspeech CLASSES WERE DELETED DUE TO DELETION OF <SPAN> TAG */
```

```html
<div class="part_of_speech">NOUN </div>
```

Comment: Could it be a problem with `line-height` or `vertical-align` of the native `<span>` style? Hard to debug without looking on an Android phone since it works fine in my desktop Chrome.

PS: maybe make the snippets with the integrated StackOverflow snippets tool so it's easier to get to them?

Comment: You can make the inner spans `display: inline-flex;` and I think it might solve the problem

Comment: I've added inline runnable code samples for your v1 and v2 to your question, and both look exactly the same to me.

Comment: Sheraff, Alon Eitan - could you please kindly modify my Code v.1 (JSFiddle allows to _save_ the updated code) to show what exactly you mean, as i'm not sure i understood you correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @Tomalak - this is the core of the problem. The result in **Android** looks the opposite, which i demonstrated with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very easy in fact: there was a conflict between `div` being present in each `span`. Deletion of `div`-component from `span`s and addition of a span selector to the *general* div made code to work as it was supposed to:

```
.part_of_speech {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.4em + 1.5vw);
}

.part_of_speech > span {
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em 0.1em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.noun {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.adjective {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}

.verb {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.adverb {
  background-color: #f94432;
}

.conjunction {
  background-color: #a047f9;
}

<div class="part_of_speech">
  <span class="noun">NOUN</span>
  <span class="adjective">ADJ.</span>
  <span class="verb">VERB</span>
  <span class="adverb">ADV.</span>
  <span class="conjunction">CONJ.</span>
</div>
```